# Как зная id медиафайла прикрепить его к записи

Tags: wordpress

Как зная id медиафайла прикрепить его к записи

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`Attachment` это тоже `post` с пост типом `attachment`. `Attachment` c `post` связываются через поле `post_parent`:

```
wp_update_post( array(
        'ID' => $attachment_id,
        'post_parent' => $post_id
    )
);
```

Либо через `$wpdb`:

```
global $wpdb;
$wpdb->query(
    "
    UPDATE $wpdb->posts 
    SET post_parent = $post_id
    WHERE ID = $attachment_id
        AND post_type = 'attachment'
    "
);
```

Comment: Да я надеялся может готовая функция есть типо set_post_attachment($post_id, $imj_id) но видимо придется ваш вариант использовать. спасибо

Comment: Есть ф-ция только для добавления изображения записи.

Comment: что за функуия то?

Comment: @ДмитрийБабанин set_post_thumbnail

Comment: если бы мне нужна была миниатюра я бы так и написал. а мне нужно что бы можно было прикрепить изображения к записи. что бы при удаление записи можно было удалить все изображения с этим. картинки загруженные через curbon не делают это автоматически. в доках долго разбираться там как поля можно расширять. как обычно нет времени. проще и быстрее привязать

Comment: Ну тогда я вам привел 2 решения, которые это делают, используйте любой вариант)

Comment: да я уже воспользовался спасибо)

Comment: @ДмитрийБабанин тогда нажимайте на галочку и стрелочку вверх возле моего ответа :)